# How to get the (absolute) path to the Download folder?

Tags: dart, flutter

In a Flutter project, how to get the (absolute) path to the Download folder in my Android device?
My Download folder is next those one: Alarms, Android, data, DCIM, Documents, Movies, Music, Notifications, Pictures, ...

Device: GALAXY S8+ SM-G955F. Android 8.0. Not Rooted. Flutter beta v0.5.1. Dart 2.0.0-dev.58.0. Windows 10

[File manager showing my Download folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtMaw.jpg)

---

Using this package `path_provider` I got those 3 paths:

```
/data/user/0/com.exemple.fonzo/cache
/data/user/0/com.exemple.fonzo/app_flutter
/storage/emulated/0
```

I cannot find or access those 3 folders from Solid-Explorer file manager on my un-rooted device GALAXY S8+ SM-G955F. Android 8.0. I just want to find the absolute path to a folder (like Download) that:

- I can access with my Android file manager app.
- I can write files in this folder from my flutter project.

Answer (score 30):

I personaly use this method :

```yaml
path_provider: 2.0.9
```

```dart
Future<String?> getDownloadPath() async {
    Directory? directory;
    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
        directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      } else {
        directory = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
        // Put file in global download folder, if for an unknown reason it didn't exist, we fallback
        // ignore: avoid_slow_async_io
        if (!await directory.exists()) directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      }
    } catch (err, stack) {
      print("Cannot get download folder path");
    }
    return directory?.path;
  }
```

Output :

- On IOS it create a folder with the name of your app and put the file inside it. Users can easily find the folder, it's intuitive.
- On Android, I test if the default download folder exist (it work most of the time), else I put inside the external storage directory (in this case, it's hard for the user to manually find the file...).

For IOS : (Mentioned by @Wai Yan)
Maybe add the follwing key in your plist.info to better see your app in document folder (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74457977/10088439).

```
UISupportsDocumentBrowser
```

Comment: for iOS you need to add some key in info.plist in order to see app folder in file app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501445/flutter-how-to-save-a-file-on-ios/74457977#74457977

Comment: This is the best method i found so far for iOS and Android. But i still hoping there's a way to save in iOS download folder too.

Answer (score 6):

Note: This package is deprecated as of Feb 2022. (See [Github repo readme](https://github.com/yasukotelin/ext_storage/blob/master/README.md))

---

I used this library to get public download directory in Android

[ext_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage)

```
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';

Future<String> _getPathToDownload() async {
  return ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
      ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
}

final String path = await _getPathToDownload();
print(path);
```

Comment: this method returns string, so can't be void.

Comment: This method returns `Future<String>` , and `print()` should be before `return`

Comment: this was not a null safety package . any alternatives ?

Comment: This pkg is dicontinued now...

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [downloads_path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/downloads_path_provider) package. You will have add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to your AndroidManifest.xml. Also if you plan to write into that folder and want your application to work for android version > 6 you must ask the user for writing permission. You could do that with https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler.
`await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions([PermissionGroup.storage]);`

Comment: the package archived by its owner

Comment: cannot use package, it is archived. So sad, i build my app month now, at the end i can not build a release.

Comment: Package is outdated

Answer (score 4):

Change the function `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` to `getExternalStorageDirectory()` it should show the external directory for the app.

Comment: I want to store my file into /storage/emulated/0/Download. How to store it? I use getExternalStorageDirectory but it store in /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myApps/files

Answer (score 3):

I simplified it without plugins
I used this code and it's working like a charm

```
Directory dir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Download');
```

Comment: This will work only for Android, not for iOS.

Comment: yes, for IOS it doesn't allow access to the download folder, instead, you have to allow the program to create its own folder and the user can access that folder

Comment: will this path remain same for all android devices or this could be different?

Answer (score 2):

You should use native feature.

At time, to access phone directory is provided by `path_provider` package .

With it, you can acceess: temporary directory, app directory, external storage.

Doc: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_provider

Comment: Which one is the download folder?

Comment: There is no one.

Comment: How can I access the download folder using this package?

Comment: nope not yet @Adnanhaider... plus i heard that there are limitations in android 11(API level 31)... didn't verify tho

Answer (score 2):

In Flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/ext_storage

Installation
Add ext_storage as a dipendency in your project pubspeck.yaml.

```
dependencies:
  ext_storage:
```

Usage
First, you write import ext_storage package.

```
import 'package:ext_storage/ext_storage.dart';
    void dirpath() async {
      var path = await ExtStorage.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(ExtStorage.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    }
```

Comment: its not null safety so its useless

Answer (score 1):

Using path provider package, you should be able to do this:

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

String? downloadDirectory;
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  final externalStorageFolder = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  if (externalStorageFolder != null) {
    downloadDirectory = p.join(externalStorageFolder.path, "Downloads");
  }
} else {
  final downloadFolder = await getDownloadsDirectory();
  if (downloadFolder != null) {
    downloadDirectory = downloadFolder.path;
  }
}
```