# Flutter - how to save a file on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter

On Android I was able to download a pdf file inside the Downloads folder using the package `downloads_path_provider`, but on IOS I got an error using this package.
If I use `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` I get the path: `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/EBB52CAB-7783-489A-B9C4-4BB7A093B8C3/Documents`
I want to put the download file inside the Files of an iphone
[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should instead use [Path Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) for accessing more than just the download directory. It's an official Flutter plugin that's easy to use.

### iOS

For accessing the document directory using `Path Provider`, use the following:

```dart
 Directory documents = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

This will allow you to store files in the document storage. You might need to add a permission for accessing the document directory within the Files app.

**EDIT:** Rafael Honda linked to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220612/how-to-save-a-text-file-in-external-storage-in-ios-using-flutter) that explains how to add that permission.

### Android

```dart
 Directory documents = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Keep in mind that both of these directories are visible to user.

Comment: I found this other question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55220612/how-to-save-a-text-file-in-external-storage-in-ios-using-flutter) and it explains how to do it, it's working now, but it's also saving other files with the pdf file that I want to save, I don't know why...

Comment: what other files?

Comment: it's some files from my app, like a firestore folder with a log file

Comment: it seems you are using the same method to download/store all files. can you share code where you provide directory or process file storing?

Comment: I'm using the dio package to download a file ```await dio.download(url, '${saveDir}/${widget.document.fileName}');``` this is my the dio download call

Comment: what is the value of the `saveDir` ?

Comment: on a physical iphone is ```/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A990B29E-804F-4DC4-9BCB-23883EB7C34D/Documents```

Comment: not actual value. in program. how do you assign value to saveDir? what method you use?

Comment: I'm using the path_provider ```getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();```

Comment: As I described in the answer. this directory is visible to user.

Comment: Ok, I believe is what I need, inside the File 'app' a folder where the user can find the file that he downloaded on my flutter app

Comment: Also, you should use `support directory` to download and store files without making it visible to user. you can use `getApplicationSupportDirectory()` for that

Comment: especially for files related to your app. like the firebase db files and logs

Comment: I got it, I not storing any db or logs files on purpose, the only file that I want to store and be visible to the user is a file which the user downloads on my app. I'm not sure why when I store that file it also stores this other files aswell

Comment: Try and clear all files and download the you want again. then check if there are anyother files, If there are check the content of the file. post it here so that we can get to the root of it

Comment: I think I know what is happening, since I made the folder visible adding the 
 lines```LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace``` ```UIFileSharingEnabled```  on the info.list file, there are some other packages in my app that store some files  using ```getApplicationSupportDirectory()``` like the package ```flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer```

Comment: that might be the reason... you can check the code on github for that plugin to know for sure

Comment: if your main issue is resolved, I suggest you upvote/accept the answer so that it can help others just like you

Comment: I just checked the ```flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer ``` package and it uses the ```getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()``` it should be using the ```getApplicationSupportDirectory()``` I guess....thanks for the help....

Comment: oh, great. you can file an issue on thier repository and give details. I am sure they'll respond to that

Comment: I set UIFileSharingEnabled, LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace & UISupportsDocumentBrowser to YES in my Info.plist.

And I'm using following code

final Directory _appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final Directory _appDocDirFolder =  Directory('${_appDocDir.path}/MY_NEW_DIR');
path = _appDocDirFolder.path+"/MyTest.txt";
file = File(path);
file.writeAsString("Hello World").then((value){
                              print(value.path);
});

Now I'm unable to see the newly created file in iOS Files App.

any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: @RamkumarMurugadoss Check if the `value.path`, after `writeAsString`, prints the same path that you intended or not. If it is the same then the file should be shown there. I don't know if it has something to do with the iOS file app or not, but also check the files by traversing through the directory programmatically to make sure that the file is there. It is possible that the file is not reflected in the iOS app immediately.

Comment: I get a permission problem when using the getApplicationDocumentsDirectory function. @Harshvardhan Joshi is there a way to fix it?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834835/os-error-operation-not-permitted-errno-1-when-create-folder-in-ios-in-flutte

Comment: How can we save file that not visible to user in android as well in ios?

Answer (score 12):

**Get the path**

For accessing the Document directory you should use a Flutter plugin for finding commonly used locations on the filesystem. The most popular is [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)

**iOS Files app**

For download files in your app's folder inside the Files app on the user's device, you should update info.plist.

UISupportsDocumentBrowser (Boolean - iOS) Specifies that the app is a document-based app and uses the UIDocumentBrowserViewController class.

If this key is set to YES, the user can set the document browser’s default save location in Settings. Additionally, the local file provider grants access to all the documents in the app’s Documents directory. These documents appear in the Files app, and in a Document Browser. Users can open and edit these document in place.

This key is supported in iOS 11 and later.

For more information read the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW37

Comment: Hey, thx for the help. Do you know if it is possible to just show some files? And others not?

Comment: Thanks You, used this in pair with Flutter_downloader

Comment: In ios 10, where i can see downloaded file?

Answer (score 8):

```
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Added these keys and tried a bunch of things, at the time of this post. The solution for me was of course to add both these two keys and use iOS 14 (14.1 to be exact) rather than iOS 15. this is because iOS 15 did not support downloading and storing in the downloads folder on emulator for some reason.

Comment: None of them are not working in my scenario.

Comment: Add to info.plist: 
 <key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key>
 <true/>
 <key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
 <true/>
 <key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
 <true/>

Comment: https://github.com/mc100p/downloadfileonios.git 

You may need to go to settings and scroll down until you see your app, after which click on it and change storage option to 'On My iPhone'.

After go to files click browse at the bottom twice, you'll see iCloud Drive and on my iPhone, because you changed the location. Click on 'On My iPhone' the file should be inside a folder (the name of your app). in my example I used getApplicationDocumentsDirectory, ensure ur using this when setting ur path or it won't work for IOS.

Answer (score 3):

[image][image]Add

> `UISupportsDocumentBrowser`

to Info.plist and set true

Then you can see the folder with your app name in file app.

But need to use

`await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();`

to save the file to be available in file app in iOs.

learn more at

Comment: To save (e.g. downloaded) files in iOS and access them via "Files" app, you need (with iOS 16.1) to set 
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key> <true/> 
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key> <true/>.  

UISupportsDocumentBrowser just lets other apps access the files as well as let the user pick a location.