# OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1 when create folder in iOS in flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter

When create a folder in iOS 15 operation system in flutter using this code:

```
Future<void> ensureInitialized() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      final docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      dataDirectory = Directory('${docDir.parent.path}/biyiapp-dev');
      if (!dataDirectory!.existsSync()) {
        dataDirectory!.createSync(recursive: true);
      }
      File sessionFile = File('${dataDirectory!.path}/session.json');
      if (sessionFile.existsSync()) {
        final String jsonString = await sessionFile.readAsString();
        lastSession = Session.fromJson(json.decode(jsonString));
      }
    }
  }
```

when I run this code in real device of iPhone XR, shows error message like this:

```
[12:27:49:427] [ERROR] {"error":"FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9024BC3C-CA76-42A5-977E-FCA9BA191FA5/biyiapp-dev' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)","message":"global error","stackTrace":"#0      _Directory.createSync (dart:io/directory_impl.dart:133)\n#1      ProAccount.ensureInitialized (package:pro_account/src/pro_account.dart:35)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n#2      DictGlobalConfig.loadApp.<anonymous closure> (package:biyi_app/config/dict_global_config.dart:22)\n<asynchronous suspension>\n"}
```

what should I do to make the flutter app could create folder in iOS real device by default?

Answer (score 0):

macOS needs you to request a specific entitlement in order to access the network. To do that open `macos/Runner/DebugProfile.entitlements` and add the following key-value pair.

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Then do the same thing in `macos/Runner/Release.entitlements`.

check [this.](https://flutter.dev/desktop#setting-up-entitlements)

Comment: are you sure it need access network? not the iOS filesystem privillege?@G H Prakash

Comment: yes @liangqicai

Comment: But the app running in the iOS operation system, not macOS operation system. @ 
G H Prakash did not have the folder. also did not have the file too. I thine we should give the app privillege to access the  NSTemporaryDirectory

Comment: @liangqicai Have you sorted out a solution to this? I got the same problem which it works on a simulator but not on ios devices.