# flutter_downloader ios can't find file after download

Tags: flutter

I am using package flutter_downloader for ios.

The file seems to be downloading fine, but I cannot find the file on my device anywhere after it is downloaded.

I download it like this:

```
 final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                        url: ref.read(resumeUrlSD),
                        headers: {}, // optional: header send with url (auth token etc)
                        // savedDir: externalDir!.path,
                        savedDir: _localPath,
                        showNotification: true,
                        openFileFromNotification: true,
                        saveInPublicStorage: _saveInPublicStorage,

                      );
```

In the console it shows:

```
externalStorageDirPath IOS: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/014DCD70-5E34-41A3-95E0-868FEA48A189/Documents
```

This is where I set up the download task:

```
late String _localPath;
  late bool _permissionReady;
  final bool _saveInPublicStorage = true;
  final ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();


  bool hasResume = false;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bindBackgroundIsolate();
    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback, step: 1);
    _prepare();

  }

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static void downloadCallback(
      String id,
      DownloadTaskStatus status,
      int progress,
      ) {

    print(
      'Callback on background isolate: '
          'task ($id) is in status ($status) and process ($progress)',
    );

    IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port')
        ?.send([id, status, progress]);

    if(status.toString() == "DownloadTaskStatus(3)" && progress == 100){
      print('2124:DOWNLOAD COMPLETE');
      FlutterDownloader.open(taskId: id);
    }

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _bindBackgroundIsolate() {
    final isSuccess = IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      _port.sendPort,
      'downloader_send_port',
    );
    if (!isSuccess) {
      _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
      _bindBackgroundIsolate();
      return;
    }
    _port.listen((dynamic data) {
      final taskId = (data as List<dynamic>)[0] as String;
      final status = data[1] as DownloadTaskStatus;
      final progress = data[2] as int;

      print(
        'Callback on UI isolate: '
            'task ($taskId) is in status ($status) and process ($progress)',
      );
      print('2124: PROGRESS $progress');

      if(progress == 100){
        print('2124: PROGRESS 100');
        OpenFilex.open(_localPath);
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Coming soon', toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, timeInSecForIosWeb: 3);
      }

      // if (_tasks != null && _tasks!.isNotEmpty) {
      //   final task = _tasks!.firstWhere((task) => task.taskId == taskId);
      //   setState(() {
      //     task
      //       ..status = status
      //       ..progress = progress;
      //   });
      // }
    });
  }

  void _unbindBackgroundIsolate() {
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
  }

  Future<void> _prepareSaveDir() async {
    _localPath = (await _getSavedDir())!;
    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    if (!savedDir.existsSync()) {
      await savedDir.create();
    }
  }

  Future<String?> _getSavedDir() async {
    String? externalStorageDirPath;

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      try {
        externalStorageDirPath = await AndroidPathProvider.downloadsPath;
        print('2124: externalStorageDirPath: $externalStorageDirPath');
      } catch (err, st) {
        print('failed to get downloads path: $err, $st');

        final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        externalStorageDirPath = directory?.path;
      }
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      externalStorageDirPath =
          (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).absolute.path;
      print('2124: externalStorageDirPath IOS: $externalStorageDirPath');

    }
    return externalStorageDirPath;
  }

  Future<void> _prepare() async {

    _permissionReady = await _checkPermission();
    if (_permissionReady) {
      await _prepareSaveDir();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _checkPermission() async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      return true;
    }

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return true;
      }

      final result = await Permission.storage.request();
      return result == PermissionStatus.granted;
    }

    throw StateError('unknown platform');
  }
```

It seems to download fine. Here is the log:

```
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(1)) and process (0)
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (1)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (3)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (5)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (7)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (9)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (11)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (13)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (15)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (17)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (19)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (21)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (23)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (25)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (27)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (29)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (31)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (33)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (35)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (37)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (39)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (41)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (43)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (45)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (47)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (49)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (51)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (53)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (56)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (58)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (60)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (62)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (64)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (66)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (68)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (70)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (72)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (74)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (76)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (78)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (80)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (82)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (84)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (86)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (88)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (90)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (92)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (94)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (96)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (98)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(2)) and process (100)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
-[FlutterDownloaderPlugin URLSession:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingToURL:] HTTP status code: 200
SuggestedFileName: --PDF.pdf
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
savedDir: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/014DCD70-5E34-41A3-95E0-868FEA48A189/Documents
filename: --PDF.pdf
flutter: Callback on background isolate: task (com.mekudeshet.download.task.31006.1683227407.679338) is in status (DownloadTaskStatus(3)) and process (100)
Query was executed successfully. Affected rows = 1
-[FlutterDownloaderPlugin URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] HTTP status code: 200
```

But I can't find it in the files folder on my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

Add to info.plist:

```
<key>UISupportsDocumentBrowser</key> <true/> 
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key> <true/> 
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key> <true/>
```

As posted here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501445/flutter-how-to-save-a-file-on-ios#:~:text=Add%20to%20info.plist%3A%20%3Ckey%3EUISupportsDocumentBrowser%3C/key%3E%20%3Ctrue/%3E%20%3Ckey%3ELSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace%3C/key%3E%20%3Ctrue/%3E%20%3Ckey%3EUIFileSharingEnabled%3C/key%3E%20%3Ctrue/%3E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59501445/flutter-how-to-save-a-file-on-ios#:%7E:text=Add%20to%20info.plist%3A%20%3Ckey%3EUISupportsDocumentBrowser%3C/key%3E%20%3Ctrue/%3E%20%3Ckey%3ELSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace%3C/key%3E%20%3Ctrue/%3E%20%3Ckey%3EUIFileSharingEnabled%3C/key%3E%20%3Ctrue/%3E)

Answer (score 0):

Usually downloaded files are inside temporary files of this app. You can use any library (for example [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) ) to localize this file.
If You want use Android `Download` folder, You need special permission (access to phone directories).

Maybe here You have everything what You need: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider
and moreover: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files